# Posting data from iphone app to server

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am sending data from iphone application to server but when it reads post String it crashes in the application and do not move forward

```
-(void)submitSurveyAnswers{


  NSString*survey_question_response_id="1";
  NSString*survey_id=@"1";

  NSString *question_id =@"1";
  NSString *survey_response_answer_id =@"1";
  NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"survey_question_response_id=%@&survey_id=%@&question_id=%@&survey_response_answer_id=%@",survey_question_response_id,survey_id,question_id,survey_response_answer_id];
  NSLog(post);
  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver-solutions.com/app/surveyAnswer.php?"];

  NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


 NSError *error;
 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

 NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@",data);

}
```

Comment: after survey_response_id,when NSString*post starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created one string with below way:

```
NSString*survey_question_response_id="1"; //Missing '@' while initializing string
```

It should be created like below way:

```
NSString*survey_question_response_id=@"1"; //Added '@' while initializing string
```

Comment: yes it is fixed now but it is not entering data in the server

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString*survey_question_response_id="1";
```

is wrong. Strings between plain double quotes are C string (0-terminated character pointers), and aren't valid NSString instances. I'm sure you wanted to 1. learn to use a debugger 2. write

```
NSString *survey_question_response_id = @"1";
```

instead.